# How to deploy Laravel project in to shared server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project, I want to deploy it into the server, the thing is that normally we have index.php and .htaccess inside the public folder, but in my case, I have brought these two files into the root. So I want to know, what are the changes needed in serve?

How can I upload this to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put back the files to the public folder. You can change the root path of your server to your project's public folder.

Follow the steps to do:

1. Go to **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**
2. Open the **.conf** file inside this folder
3. Change the **docuementRoot** to **/etc/var/www/html/project_name/public**

Restart the apache server using the following command:

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: This probably isn't possible in shared hosting.

Comment: It is possible in some hosting providers. You will get a limited access, just will not be able to update core server files.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**
Somehow you need to get the **ssh access** as a **shared user** from your hosting provider and then you can use **git** to **clone your repository** into your server.

**Solution 2**
You can copy paste all of your project into the server using ftp from your cpanel or relevant control panel.

**Solution 3**
Use Amazon as your hosting as it gives 1 year free tier access, and also gives you ssh service. Follow the solution 1 after getting this.